# A dockerized FastAPI app doesn't connect to a dockerized PostgreSQL DB

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, database-connection, fastapi

I'm pretty new to the docker stuff and I wonder why my FastAPI app can't connect to the db deployed in another container. I will deeply appreciate any help.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /code

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY . /code
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: qa_backend
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; alembic upgrade head; uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --reload'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOSTNAME=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgrespass
      - DATABASE_NAME=ques_and_ans_api
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
    networks:
      - q_a_network
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: qa_db
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgrespass
      - POSTGRES_DB=ques_and_ans_api
    networks:
      - q_a_network

networks:
  q_a_network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I run `docker compose up --build` I encounter, among other logs, the following exception:

```
qa_backend: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have reviewed similar questions here and done as users suggested, i.e. created a bridge network and specified DATABASE_HOSTNAME as "db" (postgres service's name) in the web service of my docker-compose file. But the result's the same.

Database configuration:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    SERVICE_NAME: str = 'Q&A_API'
    DB_HOST: str = '127.0.0.1'
    DB_PORT: int = 5432
    DB_USER: str
    DB_PASSWORD: str
    DB_NAME: str = 'ques_and_ans_api'
   
    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'


settings = Settings()

DATABASE_DSN: str = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{name}'.format(
    user=settings.DB_USER,
    password=settings.DB_PASSWORD,
    host=settings.DB_HOST,
    port=settings.DB_PORT,
    name=settings.DB_NAME
)
```

Comment: If set, the `container_name` is the dns name of the container. Thus, `DATABASE_HOSTNAME=db` should be `DATABASE_HOSTNAME=qa_db`.

Comment: Your error message says `127.0.0.1`, which implies the `DATABASE_HOSTNAME` environment variable isn't getting used.  What does the database configuration in your application look like?  Is that error message coming out of the build phase or when actually running the container?  (I'd expect either the Compose service name or the container name to work, but the error message has neither.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the comment. I added configuration code to the body of the question. I would really appreciate if you take a look at it. The error message is coming out when the container is being run.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you a lot for the comment. I changed 'db' to 'qa_db', but it didn't help.

Comment: Your `settings` object uses `DB_HOST`, but the Compose setting spells out `DATABASE_HOSTNAME`.  You also may need to explicitly use `os.getenv()` to retrieve values from the environment if present.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thank you so much, you are my saviour! Now it's working fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze, you can publish the answer so that I could mark it as the answer that helped in order to level up a little your reputation and all, if you want of course.